# sequelize with async and find method

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

First apology for my poor english.

I am unable to access the updated vehicle.vsr.selectedvalues outside the find method.

Steps i followed

1) i have a vehicles array and their vsrdetails associated. 
2) I am trying to add one more element(contractor_name) in the existing vehicle JSON.
3) For this i am forming new array and send to response.

Impedement is that i am unable to access the updated vehicle.vsr details outside the find method.

```
     async.forEach(vehicles, function(vehicle, callback){ 
     newvehicles.push(vehicle.selectedValues)
     Contractor.find({ 'where': { 'id': (vehicle.vsr.contractor_id).toString().trim() } }).success(function(contractor){
        console.log(vehicle.vsr.contractor_id +"======"+ contractor.name + "========"+  vehicle.vsr.project_id)
        var vsrnew = Array()
        console.log("***************************************************")
        console.log(newvehicles)
        vehicle.vsr.selectedValues["contractor_name"] = contractor.name
        vsrnew.push(vehicle.vsr.selectedValues)
        newvehicles["vsr"] = vehicle.vsr.selectedValues
      })

     callback() 
   },function(){
      return res.json({ "total": total, "start": start, "limit": limit, "items": newvehicles })
  })
```

Appreciate your patience.

Answer (score 1):

Some things I am seeing:

Where are your semicolons?!! : )

Your line `newvehicles["vsr"] = vehicle.vsr.selectedValues;` is assigning the same value each time. I see you use `.push()` to add new items to that array at the tope (I think that is your intent from the JSON response property name "items"), and you should do the same at that line. Or assign to a new sub-element.

The variable `vehicle` is only part of the `find()` method due to the `async.forEach` call - the per-item function has a variable named `vehicle` that can be accessed in that function scope.

Don't create the new Array (`var vsrnew = Array()`) in the `.find()` if you want to use it outside of that.

Will gladly comment more, update your question with specifics.

Comment: Heartful thanks for your update,                                               Ignore semicolons. Got It

Comment: Hi @clay, In the above question. I am fetching a record and adding new element called contractor_name in the same object and pushing into an new array. Upto here every thing is working fine. Now my concern is, new array is not forming as vehicles list, bcoz it is async process. how to avoid this, vehicles retrieved as sorted order  after that i want to fetch contractors.

Comment: You need to make sure the object/array you are pushing into is defined above the `async.each` call. Otherwise the scope is within the `each` function and then lost when the scope dies. You may need to sort at the end of `async.each`, once you have all the elements you want.